# react-native how to limit maximum scrollTo in flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, pager

I want to make flat list seem like page layout, is there any way to limit maximum scroll to 1 item in flatlist? or any good way in to make page layout with photo list?

```
const renderPhoto = ({item:photo})=> {
    console.log("rendering photo");
    return (
    <Photo 
    {...photo}/>
      )
  }

<FlatList
        style={{width:"100%"}}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={data?.seePhoto} 
        keyExtractor={item =>""+ item.id}
        horizontal={true}
        renderItem={renderPhoto}  
      />
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the [pagingEnabled](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#pagingenabled) property of the `FlatList`?

Comment: Not yet, I'm gonna try that, thank you